# Change paragraph text on click

Tags: html, css, text, paragraph

I've been using javascript (with a very limited knowledge) to swap images but now I want to do it with text.

My question is, if I have 10 different paragraphs (link 1 shows paragraph 1, link 2 shows paragraph 2 etc), I don't understand where I can 'type' them. My images obviously link to a ready made file but I want my text to remain as text and I'm not sure how I assign this in either CSS or HTML etc.

CODE USED:

So far I have my CSS code to define my text content (that I want to change depending on the clicking) and my map content where I'm controlling the change in text:

```
    #content 
    #content div {float:left;}  
    #content_map {width:595px;}     
    #content_text {width:290px;;}
    #content_profile {width:900px;}
```

So my html so far for the map 'hotspots' are as an example:

```
  <area shape="circle" coords="276,326,15" href="#" alt="Kinnloch" onclick="MM_swapImage('stboswells_01','','discover_kinnloch.png',1)"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="202,264,11" href="#" alt="Lochinver" onclick="MM_swapImage('stboswells_01','','discover_lochinver.png',1)"/>
```

...
etc

so basically I'm swapping images in the 'profile' div by the coordinates on the 'map' div and what i want to do is use these coordinates to also swop in text in my 'text' div so the first set of coords would change my text div with 'Paragraph 1' and the second set of coordinates would change my text div to 'Paragraph 2' etc...

Comment: I've just edited my query to include the fact the text is a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can add a class to each `area` element, then target it like so:

```
$(".areaClass").click(function(){
    $("your text div id/class").text("Discover " + $(this).attr("alt"));
});
```

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/Vphf2/

I changed the `area` to anchor links so that it would show up on screen, but it should work the same for your case as well

Comment: Thank you for helping. The text is actually a paragraph of long text - is there another way of storing it without using the alt?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, but this i modified the sample a little bit here http://jsfiddle.net/Vphf2/1/